# In what language is Gingerbread OS written?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread

Are all versions of Android written in the same language or in different languages?

Answer (score 2):

Not Gingerbread-specific, but according to [Ohloh](http://www.ohloh.net/p/android), Android was created using:

- C
- C++
- Java
- Others

Comment: +1 Also ARM Assembler, and Java runs on the Dalvik VM instead of a standard VM because it is compiled to ARM Assembly code before it is put on the device.